# how to login with access token in Spring Security

Tags: oauth-2.0

My project is applied spring security and google ouath2 login.
after user login my web site stores access token in cookie. i want to make user who has access token cookie can access without login. currently if user close the browser, user should login again whether user has token or not.

Comment: What is the issue you are using facing?

Comment: The user must login too often.
After first login, I want the user to login about once a week.

Comment: You should have a look at cookie settings. If you make a cookie valid until a given date/time then the browser will keep the cookie even when the tab gets closed. Otherwise, the cookie is dropped when the tab/browser is closed.

Comment: user have still token if browser closed. that's no problem. but spring security requests login again to user who have already token.